# How to Make Input Checkbox Update Price Total Using Values + Include Additional Fees for Total?

Tags: javascript, html

So I made this basic checkbox price app that updates the food price whenever you click on a checkbox option https://codepen.io/shodoro/pen/GRQNXyq

However, I had to hard code the prices in the javascript, but I want to know how I can update the prices based on the value in the input tag

So for this example in the index.html the value is set to 10, so instead of hard coding the price of 10 in JS, I can just add the value attribute instead

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="item1" id="item1" value="10" onClick="updatePrice()">
```

Also, how would I make my code scalable? because right now I wrote a bunch of if else if else statments manually, however if I were to add 50 new menu items, then that wouldn't be feasible for my JS code.

```
 function updatePrice() {
        let price = 0.00;
        if (document.getElementById("item1").checked == true) {
            price = 10;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("item2").checked == true && document.getElementById("item1").checked == true) {
            price = 17;
        } else if(document.getElementById("item2").checked == true) {
            price = 7
        }

        if (document.getElementById("item3").checked == true && document.getElementById("item1").checked == true && document.getElementById("item2").checked == true) {
            price = 20;
        } else if (document.getElementById("item3").checked == true && document.getElementById("item1").checked == true) {
            price = 13
        } else if (document.getElementById("item3").checked == true && document.getElementById("item2").checked == true) {
            price = 10
        } else if (document.getElementById("item3").checked == true){
            price = 3
        }

        document.getElementById("price").innerText = "Your order total is: $" + price;
    }
```

Lastly, I have the basic total part for the food to work, but I don't know how I would convert my JS code to also include the delivery fees, taxes, tip % added to the final total?

Any ideas?

Comment: What does data(50 new menu items) look like? 
Is it look like this? `['12 piece wings $10','12 piece wings $10','12 piece wings $10', ... ]`

Comment: Best is to have a array of json that contains the list of items and their prices then use js to add the checkboxes to Dom along side onChange event listener on the checkboxes that call the function and passes the item info that contain the price and all other info

Comment: @Dali yeah basically an infinite number of menu items

Comment: @makerbaker You can check my code based on data, so you can put an infinite number of menu-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that...

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form'];

myForm.reset();

myForm.oninput =_=>
  {
  let sum = 0;

  ['item1','item2','item3'].forEach( chkBxNm => 
    {
    if (myForm[chkBxNm].checked) sum += +myForm[chkBxNm].value
    })  

  myForm.total.textContent = `Your order total is: $${sum}`
  }

  myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()  // disable submit
  }
```

```css
label,
output {
  display: block;
  }
output {
  color      : green;
  font-size  : 1.4em;
  margin-top : 1.2em;
  }
```

```html
<form action="" name="my-form">

  <label><input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="10">  12 piece wings $10</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="7">  6 piece wings $7</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="3">  Large fries $3</label>

  <output name="total">Your order total is: $0 </output>

</form>
```

or

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form'];

myForm.reset();

myForm.oninput =_=>
  {
  let sum = 0;

  myForm.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach( chkBx => 
    {
    if (chkBx.checked) sum += +chkBx.value
    })  

  myForm.total.textContent = `Your order total is: $${sum}`
  }
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()  // disable submit
  }
```

```css
label,
output {
  display: block;
  }
output {
  color      : green;
  font-size  : 1.4em;
  margin-top : 1.2em;
  }
```

```html
<form action="" name="my-form">

  <label><input type="checkbox" value="10">  12 piece wings $10</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="7">  6 piece wings $7</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="3">  Large fries $3</label>

  <output name="total">Your order total is: $0 </output>

</form>
```

Comment: why did you use the form tag for this? Because I had other input tags for emails, name etc that I didn't show on the html

Comment: also what is this =_=> code from? I've never seen that before

Comment: @makerbaker In any form, inputs elements are children, you don't need to use id for them.  `=_=>` is the same as `= e =>` but the code below didn't use this argument and the caracter `_` as argument is conventionnal in ninja code

Comment: @makerbaker if you have other inputs types you may prefer to use formData to read them

Answer (score 0):

To read the prices dynamically from the `value` property of the checkboxes, not much is missing. All that is needed is to read the "value" property of the corresponding element. If you only want to calculate the prices together, the following code is all you need.

Add a class to your checkbox elements. In this case its class `item`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item1" id="item1" class="item" value="10" onClick="updatePrice()">
```

Then you can loop through all the checkboxes with the class `item` and calculate the price dynamically:

```
function updatePrice() {
    let price = 0.00;
    const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

    for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked) price += Number(checkboxes[i].value);
    }

    document.getElementById("price").innerText = "Your order total is: $" + price;
}
```

Comment: but if I want to add infinite menu items i can't use this

Comment: Here in the example, every existing menu item with the class `item` is included in the price calculation. You can create an infinite number of menu items and evaluate them with this method. How you create the menu items is up to you. Do you need an example to dynamically generate a list of "infinite" menu items?

Answer (score 0):

here is the easy solution for this code https://codepen.io/mallick-portfolio/pen/KKQNbZZ?editors=1010
you can add more checkboxes
that will automatically calculate the price.

js here

```
function updatePrice() {
let price = 0.00;
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked) price += parseInt(checkboxes[i].value);
}

document.getElementById("price").innerText = "Your order total is: $" + price;
```

}
updatePrice()

Answer (score 0):

1. Total price is updated by value of input.
2. I create JS based on `data` array which you told. 
    So you don't have to worry about how long the data will be.
3. I'm not sure the formula of total price I wrote is what you want, but you can see the total price also updated. You can change the detail option at `priceOption` object.

```js
const data = ["12 piece wings $10", "6 piece wings $7", "Large fries $3"];
const priceOption = {
  tax: 0.1,
  deliveryFee: 5,
  tip: 0.2
};
let foodPrice = 0;

const $menuItems = document.querySelector(".menu-items");
$menuItems.addEventListener("click", (e) => updatePrice(e));

data.map((item, idx) => {
  const [name, price] = item.split("$");
  const menu = `
    <div class="menu-item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item${idx}" id="item${idx}" value=${price} class="item">
      <label for="item${idx}">
        ${name} 
        $<span class="itemPrice">${price}</span>
      </label>
     </div>
    `;
  $menuItems.innerHTML += menu;
});

function updatePrice(e) {
  const $itemPrice =
    e.target.querySelector(".menu-item input.item") ||
    e.target.closest(".menu-item input.item");
  if (!$itemPrice) return;
  const $foodPrice = document.querySelector(".foodPrice");
  const $totalPrice = document.querySelector(".totalPrice");

  const price = +$itemPrice.value;
  const isChecked = $itemPrice.checked;

  foodPrice = isChecked ? foodPrice + price : foodPrice - price;
  const totalPrice =
    foodPrice * (1 + priceOption.tax + priceOption.tip) +
    priceOption.deliveryFee;
  $foodPrice.textContent = `$${foodPrice}`;
  $totalPrice.textContent = `$${totalPrice}`;
}
```

```css
.foodPrice {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Order Details</h2>
  <div class="menu-items"></div>
</div>
<div class="payment">
  <h2>Payment Summary</h2>
  <p>Food Total <span class="foodPrice">$0.00</span></p>
  <p>Tax 10%</p>
  <p>Delivery Fee $5.00</p>
  <p>Tip (20%)</p>
  <p>Your order total is: <span class="totalPrice">$0.00</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = ["12 piece wings $10", "6 piece wings $7", "Large fries $3"];
const priceOption = {
  tax: 0.1,
  deliveryFee: 5,
  tip: 0.2
};
let foodPrice = 0;

const $menuItems = document.querySelector(".menu-items");
$menuItems.addEventListener("click", (e) => updatePrice(e));

data.map((item, idx) => {
  const [name, price] = item.split("$");
  const menu = `
    <div class="menu-item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item${idx}" id="item${idx}" value=${price} class="item">
      <label for="item${idx}">
        ${name} 
        $<span class="itemPrice">${price}</span>
      </label>
     </div>
    `;
  $menuItems.innerHTML += menu;
});

function updatePrice(e) {
  const $itemPrice =
    e.target.querySelector(".menu-item input.item") ||
    e.target.closest(".menu-item input.item");
  if (!$itemPrice) return;
  const $foodPrice = document.querySelector(".foodPrice");
  const $totalPrice = document.querySelector(".totalPrice");

  const price = +$itemPrice.value;
  const isChecked = $itemPrice.checked;

  foodPrice = isChecked ? foodPrice + price : foodPrice - price;
  const totalPrice =
    foodPrice * (1 + priceOption.tax + priceOption.tip) +
    priceOption.deliveryFee;
  $foodPrice.textContent = `$${foodPrice}`;
  $totalPrice.textContent = `$${totalPrice}`;
}
```

```css
.foodPrice {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Order Details</h2>
  <div class="menu-items"></div>
</div>
<div class="payment">
  <h2>Payment Summary</h2>
  <p>Food Total <span class="foodPrice">$0.00</span></p>
  <p>Tax 10%</p>
  <p>Delivery Fee $5.00</p>
  <p>Tip (20%)</p>
  <p>Your order total is: <span class="totalPrice">$0.00</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).